# Mosquitto MQTT SSL with Certificates throwing Errors

Tags: mqtt, iot, mosquitto

I am running mosquitto mqtt broker on Ubuntu AWS EC2 instance. It runs absolutely fine without SSL. I have now edited the default.conf file to :

```
allow_anonymous false

password_file /etc/mosquitto/passwd

#listener 1883
#NON SECURE PORT

listener 1884
certfile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain/fullchain.pem
```

Where fullchain.pem I have got from Lets Encrypt's certbot. The same directory also has cert.pem, chain.pem and privkey.pem.

When I run the following commands, it throws errors :

```
mosquitto_sub -h localhost -t "test" -u "User" -P "Pass" --cert /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain/fullchain.pem
Error: Both certfile and keyfile must be provided if one of them is set.

mosquitto_sub -h localhost -t "test" -u "User" -P "Pass" --cert /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain/fullchain.pem --key etc/letsencrypt/live/domain/privkey.pem
Error: Connection refused
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to pass a `keyfile` in your `mosquitto.conf`. As I pointed out in your last question the reason it won't start is that by default the file is only readable by the `root` user. You will need to change the permissions on the file so the `mosquitto` user can read the file if you want to use it with mosquitto.

Second, you should NOT be using the LetsEncrypt cert/key files with the client. The client only needs cert/keys if you are using mutual TLS/SSL authentication, but it makes no sense to use LetsEncrypt certificates to autheticate the client, because LetsEncrypt will issue certificates to anybody, so there would be nothing to stop me using one to connect to your broker.

If you want to do mutual TLS/SSL authentication then you should look at setting up your own Certificate Authority. You can continue to use LetsEncrypt to issue a certificate for the broker, the client certificates do not need to (and probably normally should NOT be) issued by the same CA.

Once you have the `keyfile` setup in the the `mosquitto.conf` file, you would then connect to the broker as follows:

```
mosquitto_sub -h localhost -p 1884 --tls-use-os-certs -t "test" -u "User" -P "Pass"
```

The `--tls-use-os-certs` tells the client to use the OS's CA cert bundle to authenticate the brokers certificate. If needed you could replace that with `--cafile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain/chain.pem` but that should not be needed.